# Lev. 12:2 confirms Luke 2:22 is "Her Purification" rather than "their"

Tags: luke

Doesn't Lev. 12:2 confirm the accurate translation of Luke 2:22 being "Her Purification", (rather than "their"), as the law of Moses states?

Answer (score 1):

Hers or theirs are both accurate.

Leviticus 15:

> 19 And if a woman have an issue, and her issue in her flesh be blood, she shall be put apart seven days: and whosoever toucheth her shall be unclean until the even.
>   20 And every thing that she lieth upon in her separation shall be unclean: every thing also that she sitteth upon shall be unclean.
>   21 And whosoever toucheth her bed shall wash his clothes, and bathe himself in water, and be unclean until the even.
>   22 And whosoever toucheth any thing that she sat upon shall wash his clothes, and bathe himself in water, and be unclean until the even.
>   23 And if it be on her bed, or on any thing whereon she sitteth, when he toucheth it, he shall be unclean until the even.

*22 And whosoever toucheth any thing that she sat upon shall wash his clothes, and bathe himself in water, and be unclean until the even.*

This implies that while she remains unclean, the baby will also have uncleanness because she's in constant bodily contact as it's carer.
So whether the mother and the baby are the subject, or only the mother, either choice in 'their' or 'her' uncleanness, is still a valid reflection of Leviticus 15.